# How to interpret the prediction of H2ORF on regression tasks?

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I am confused by the output of H2ORandomForestEstimator model.

So my task is predicting house price, which is a regression task.

training:

```
model = H2ORandomForestEstimator(ntrees=100, max_depth=20,mtries=-1, seed=42, score_each_iteration=True)
model.train(x=features, y=target, training_frame=train_frame)
```

the data has around 80 features

and i predict on the test data, which contain 1495 rows (aka. data points)

```
log_predict = model.predict(test_frame)
```

but the shape of log_predict is (1459, 656), which is really confusing, and this is a screenshot of the output:[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prGFs.png)
(sorry i am not able to embed picture yet...)

What does the number 656 mean? And is there any convenient way to transform it to a (1459,1) array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have converted your response column into a factor column (I can't tell for sure because you don't have all of your code there), so it's doing classification instead of regression.  Your screenshot of the prediction output shows a multiclass output (with 655 "classes").

It's also possible you had quotes around the numbers in the CSV file and H2O interpreted them as categories instead of numbers.  You will need to convert the response column back to numeric and then re-train your model:

```
train_frame[target] = train_frame[target].asnumeric()
```